# Debugging Android native code with GDB is painfully slow

Tags: android, eclipse, gdb, android-ndk

I use Eclipse and GDB (ndk-gdb) to debug native C++ code in an Android app I'm just porting. Debugging the Java side in Eclipse is ok, but debugging the C++ code is so slow that it's hardly feasible. Stepping from one statement to the next takes about 25s on an up-to-date PC. I also keep getting errors like this one

org.eclipse.cdt.debug.mi.core.cdi.MI2CDIException: Target is not responding (timed out)[]

while debugging which don't seem to adversely affect the program flow, but do indicate there is some issue. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I get that error when my gdb and eclipse debuggers are out of sync. Usually when I start, I'll break on the load-library line in Java, step over, start ndk-gdb, if I restart debugging Java before 'continue'-ing in gdb I get errors like that... Similar case happens when trying to exit the Java debugger while gdb is paused.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the android emulator? If so have you already tried these steps to speed it up? ---> https://www.virag.si/2012/10/speeding-up-android-emulator/